# По пробужденИИ или по пробужденИЮ — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Однако было время, когда ни в какой степени подпития его не привлекла бы женщина, что явилась ему **по пробуждении** нынче утром.*
[**К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоем**](http://knijky.ru/books/chut-svet-s-sobakoyu-vdvoem?page=58)

*Мир шифрует стихи во снах. Шифрует почище красавицы Нины. Ни вытянуть, ни запомнить, ни записать **по пробуждению.***
[**Д. Воденников (из статьи)**](https://www.gazeta.ru/comments/column/vodennikov/s63353/10899620.shtml?updated)

Я "споткнулась" о первое предложение, когда читала книгу. Продукт поисков решения — отрывок из статьи (выражение встречается нечасто).
Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Благодарю за правку, Вы **очень внимательны**.

Comment: Да не за что, Римма.))

Answer (score 3):

В значении *после пробуждения - по пробуждении*. [Источник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 3):

Правильно, конечно же, "по пробуждени**и**" ("по прибытии", "по завершении" более типично - после чего). Иное для газетных журналистов простительно (даже в программе "Время" иногда проскакивает "по прилёт**у**"), да и можно надеяться, что это осталось только в сетевой версии. В другом контексте и смысле было бы наоборот:

> По пробуждени**ю** [*по какому признаку*] их узнаете их.